# file_get_contents() error: failed to open stream : invalid argument

Tags: php, file-get-contents, invalid-argument

```
$i = 0;   

$name_url = '../../accounts/full/'.$frd_array[$i].'/profile/name.txt';
$name = file_get_contents($name_url);
$user_id = file_get_contents('../../accounts/full/'.$frd_array[$i].'/profile/user_id.txt');
$status = file_get_contents('../../accounts/full/'.$frd_array[$i].'/profile/status.txt');

echo "
        <div class='frd_acc'>
        <img class='c_avatar' src='../accounts/full/".$frd_array[$i]."/profile/avatar.png'>
        <div class='c_name'>".$name."</div> <kbd class='c_user_id'>".$user_id."</kbd>
        <div class='status'>".$status."</div>
        </div>"
```

above is my php code. when im executing this php script im getting the following errors:

> Warning: file_get_contents(../../accounts/full/amaan2 amaan2 /profile/name.txt): failed to open stream: Invalid argument in E:\FreeJi\php\chats\my_frds.php on line 16
>   Warning: file_get_contents(../../accounts/full/amaan2 amaan2 /profile/user_id.txt): failed to open stream: Invalid argument in E:\FreeJi\php\chats\my_frds.php on line 17
>   Warning: file_get_contents(../../accounts/full/amaan2 amaan2 /profile/status.txt): failed to open stream: Invalid argument in E:\FreeJi\php\chats\my_frds.php on line 18

Please Help ME!!!

Comment: Can you do a var_dump($name_url) above file_get_contents and post your results here?

Comment: is this correct? full/amaan2 amaan2 /profile repeat the same word twice, with space in between and space after then `/`?

Comment: @AlexiosTsiaparas yeah sure. I post it as a update

Comment: E:\FreeJi\php\chats\my_frds.php:19:boolean false

E:\FreeJi\php\chats\my_frds.php:19:boolean false

E:\FreeJi\php\chats\my_frds.php:19:boolean false

Comment: @Andreas yes it is correct

Comment: The paths you post here in comments above is not nearly the same as the ones in your code. Not sure I understand

Comment: sorry I didn't get you

Comment: Can you post your directory structure?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145758/discussion-between-shaikh-amaan-fm-and-andreas).

Comment: @ShaikhAmaanFM The file_get_contents is equivalent to file_get_contents('../../accounts/full/amaan2 amaan2 /profile/name.txt'). Can you do a var_dump(getcwd()) as well, and check if the complete path to the file is correct? Note that there is a space at the second amaan2, so this might be a problem

Comment: @AlexiosTsiaparas yes it is but I need those names "amaan2 amaan2" in variables only.

Comment: Then can you do a $name_url = '../../accounts/full/'.trim($frd_array[$i]).'/profile/name.txt'; and see if it fixes it.

Comment: The issue is probably E:\accounts/full/amaan2 amaan2 In chat you said your directory is E:\freeji/full/amaan2 amaan2. If you are in file E:\FreeJi\php\chats\my_frds.php and go back two directories you go to E:\FreeJi\. It sounds like you have confused yourself in all the directories.

Comment: @AlexiosTsiaparas I noticed that sapce before but Im not getting how to remove that.

Comment: Is it the space that is the issue? I asked you about that 23 minutes ago. It's not in the array it's in the code. `$frd_array[$i].'/profile`

Comment: if you do a trim as in trim($frd_array[$i]) it will go away

Comment: @Andreas oh sorry sir I did a slight mistake in represting the directory structure to you in chat the thing above is correct one sorry again

Comment: @AlexiosTsiaparas It's not in the array. see comment above

Comment: @AlexiosTsiaparas yeah I trimmed it before but the problem still remains the same

Comment: Sorry that was my misstake, it only looked like a space here on SO.

Comment: @AlexiosTsiaparas yes!! it worked the thing you stated in the comment. I did that way and got my work done thank you

Comment: @AlexiosTsiaparas post this thing as answer I'll accept it.

Comment: Seriously?? I asked you an half an hour ago about the space. And now you get it? And want to accept "his answer"?

Comment: @Andreas I told you that I trimmed that before and it didn't worked out. but the way he stated, I got my work done.

Comment: You didn't say anything about trim, you wrote `@Andreas yes it is correct ` nothing else.

Comment: @Andreas sorry sir I thought that before and had did that but as it didn't work I thought there's nothing we got to do with it. than when he stated it I thought let it give a try.

Comment: Still it's not "his" answer is it?

Comment: @AlexiosTsiaparas whatever happened sir. you could have helped me long ago. so if you'll put your answer here I'll accept your one

Comment: @Andreas sorry Andreas he worked more than you behind this problem and he could have solved that before you if I did not have done a mistake there

Comment: oh sorry I messed up with u guyz names

Comment: whatever I meant here with Andreas, I wanted those things to meant with @AlexiosTsiaparas

Comment: @ShaikhAmaanFM Unaccept my answer and you can select any one that you like

Comment: @AlexiosTsiaparas thank for understanding the situation

Comment: In my opinion the answer is not trim(). It may solve the problem for now, but it's not the solution. You have an array with username that holds an extra space or a directory that lacks a space. That is inconsistent. Inconsistent is bad in programming. This time the "solution" was trim, but what if a user has a space as the last char? You trim it and you are back here with "why won't it work?". Go back and figure out why your array and directories don't match. That is the answer and solution in my opinion. Anything else is band-aid, or not even that more like duct tape and a piece of paper.

Comment: I'll have a look at that Thank You everyone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please do

```
$name_url = '../../accounts/full/'.trim($frd_array[$i]).'/profile/name.t‌​xt';
```

in order to remove extra spaces

Answer (score 0):

Try $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/accounts/full/'

Comment: I did this but still the problem exist

Comment: id need to see a var_dump of $frd_array

Comment: E:\FreeJi\php\chats\my_frds.php:19:
array (size=2)
  0 => string 'amaan2 amaan2

' (length=15)
  1 => string 'shaikh_amaan_fm amaan' (length=21)